# How to construct current concrete type from within abstract class?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

I have an abstract class `AxisState` with two concrete subclasses `XState` and `YState`. They're supposed to be immutable objects with a bunch of methods that return a different `AxisState`. Most of these methods are completely defined in `AxisState`, and a few of them are abstract and implemented in the concrete subclasses.

The problem is that I need to somehow return a new instance of the current concrete subtype of `AxisState` from within the methods entirely implemented in `AxisState`.

What I'm currently doing is implementing a method `abstract AxisState NewStateOfSameType()` which is implemented as returning a new `XState` or `YState` from within these subtypes, respectively.

```
public abstract class AxisState {
    public abstract AxisState NewStateOfSameType(/*...*/);
    public abstract AxisState OverloadMethod();
    public abstract AxisState AnotherOverloadMethod();

    public AxisState(int fieldOne, int fieldTwo) {
        // ...
    } 

    public AxisState NextState(/*...*/) {
        // ...
        return NewStateOfSameType(fieldOne, fieldTwo);
    }

    // ...
}
```

And the implementation in `XState`/`YState`:

```
public class XState : AxisState {    
    public XState(int fieldOne, int fieldTwo) : base(fieldOne, fieldTwo) {}
    
    public override AxisState NewStateOfSameType(int fieldOne, int fieldTwo) {
        return new XState(fieldOne, fieldTwo);
    }

    // Abstract methods implemented here
}
```

```
public class YState : AxisState {    
    public YState(int fieldOne, int fieldTwo) : base(fieldOne, fieldTwo) {}
    
    public override AxisState NewStateOfSameType(int fieldOne, int fieldTwo) {
        return new YState(fieldOne, fieldTwo);
    }

    // Abstract methods implemented here
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to handle all this, or some way to restructure this whole thing?

Comment: What do these classes try to achieve? (XState, YState) What is the difference between them? What do they have in common? Are the differences more "logical" than in what they achieve as classes? Are you trying to create XState from XState and YState from YState? (For this You might be able to instead use a generic base class.)

Comment: The reason I ask is that maybe one class would suffice (AxisState) and you would have one instance of AxisState called XState and another called YState

Comment: They're essentially the same structure with the same fields and methods, but some of the methods are implemented one way in XState and another in YState (so there is some logical difference).

Comment: Yes I am trying to create XState from XState and YState from YState.

Comment: Perhaps this question helps you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects

Comment: @JoseLuis My objects are immutable so I can't make changes to them after they've been cloned.